# MSSQL group by all columns of Actor table

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I need to group by all detail about an actor. Means I need all the columns
what I done so far is this:

```
SELECT Actor.Actor_id AS A,(MAX(Movie.M_year))-(MIN(Movie.M_year))AS DIFF
FROM Actor INNER JOIN (Movie INNER JOIN Acted_in ON (Acted_in.Movie_id=Movie.Movie_id))
ON (Actor.Actor_id=Acted_in.Actor_id)
GROUP BY Actor.Actor_id
```

How can I fix this and select all columns? I can do this only for id column.

Comment: SORRY MY MISTAKE..NOT STUDENTS --ACTOR

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. try this:

```
SELECT Actor.Actor_id AS A,(MAX(Movie.M_year))-(MIN(Movie.M_year))AS DIFF
FROM Actor INNER JOIN Acted_in ON Actor.Actor_id=Acted_in.Actor_id
INNER JOIN Movie ON Acted_in.Movie_id=Movie.Movie_id
GROUP BY Actor.Actor_id
```

If you want more columns then you can add that as:

```
SELECT Actor.Actor_id AS A,(MAX(Movie.M_year))-(MIN(Movie.M_year))AS DIFF, 
       Actor.someCol1, Actor.someCol2
FROM Actor INNER JOIN Acted_in ON Actor.Actor_id=Acted_in.Actor_id
INNER JOIN Movie ON Acted_in.Movie_id=Movie.Movie_id
GROUP BY Actor.Actor_id, Actor.someCol1, Actor.someCol2
```

Comment: actually i need  actor with all details who have the biggest diff

Comment: but i cant enter a max on max ..how can i do this?

Comment: @DANA Use `ORDER BY diff DESC LIMIT 1` to get the actor with the biggest diff.

Comment: the limit 1 is the top?it doesnt work ..only desc is working

Comment: @DANA I thought you were using MySQL, this is another difference. In SQL-Server you use `SELECT TOP 1 ...`

Comment: thank you..anyway you have a basic answer ..?how can i return only the biggest diff ?not only descendent ..the limit 1 wont work

Comment: oh i see your comments in delay.. i put select top 1 where?

Comment: @DANA: `SELECT TOP 1 Actor.Actor_id AS A,(MAX(Movie.M_year))-(MIN(Movie.M_year))AS DIFF, 
       Actor.someCol1, Actor.someCol2
FROM Actor INNER JOIN Acted_in ON Actor.Actor_id=Acted_in.Actor_id
INNER JOIN Movie ON Acted_in.Movie_id=Movie.Movie_id
GROUP BY Actor.Actor_id, Actor.someCol1, Actor.someCol2`

Comment: and do you know how in this sql i can return all columns with the * ? without writing all the columns names?